GitHub CI not pulling latest submodule revision
I'm experiencing a very strange issue. I will share the code and repos since everything is open source.
I have a submodule defined in .gitmodules as shown here:
[submodule "packages/sdk/lib/contracts"]
    path = packages/sdk/lib/contracts
    url = https://github.com/ionicprotocol/contracts
    branch = development

https://github.com/ionicprotocol/monorepo/blob/development/.gitmodules#L4
In my GitHub CI, I am failing recent jobs because the submodule revision that's checked out is an old revision:
'packages/sdk/lib/contracts'
  Cloning into '/home/runner/work/monorepo/monorepo/packages/sdk/lib/contracts'...
  From https://github.com/ionicprotocol/contracts
   * branch            f34adca4d882b65310e21b8b9df01df32026ac09 -> FETCH_HEAD

https://github.com/ionicprotocol/monorepo/actions/runs/9189715243/job/25272345929?pr=374
The latest commit is 2493935081b4bdfe64d1ecd12f2f5141284347fe.
I can see locally when I run git submodule it's showing the latest commit.
I cannot figure out where this old commit would be stored, and GitHub CI is not set up to cache anything AFAICT.
Everything worked locally once I ran git pull --recurse-submodules.
Any help would be appreciated!

I cloned the repository with the command
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/ionicprotocol/monorepo.git

The checked out branch is the default development:
$ cd monorepo
$ git branch
* development

Let's see what submodule's commit the superproject stores in the HEAD:
$ git rev-parse development:packages/sdk/lib/contracts
f34adca4d882b65310e21b8b9df01df32026ac09

The command can be simplified for the current commit:
$ git rev-parse @:packages/sdk/lib/contracts
f34adca4d882b65310e21b8b9df01df32026ac09

Exactly what CI sees.
If you want to update the submodule to the latest commit at remote you also need to update the superproject:
$ cd packages/sdk/lib/contracts
$ git switch development
$ git show --format=%H
2493935081b4bdfe64d1ecd12f2f5141284347fe

$ cd ../../../.. # back to the superproject
$ git add packages/sdk/lib/contracts
$ git commit -m 'Update submodule `contracts`'
$ git push

Another variant:
$ git submodule update --remote
$ git commit -m 'Update submodule `contracts`'
$ git push

See the docs.

Wow I could swear I tried this exact command, but I followed your instructions exactly and it worked! Thanks so much!
